# how to check if an element in an html file exists in another html file?

Tags: functions, html, html5

Imagine that I have an HTML file as one of my WordPress blog pages (let's call it page B). I want to write an if condition inside a tag on page B to check if a specific element exists on another web page (page A).

My question is what function should I choose to check this condition? Should I also import the HTML file of page A inside page B?
And what should I do on the server-side, if I have to?

Thanks

Comment: Are you referring to the post content or do you have literal `.html` files in your site? What problem does this solve? It's a little too abstract/generic at the moment so context will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, and you want to find an HTML element inside another page, you need to use some HTML parser.

Take a look at https://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtmlfile.php or https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser. I believe there are more tools that can help you with this.

On page B you load page A as a remote document by URL, then parse it and look for the desired HTML element.